# tkinter - How to clear a label when button is clicked for second time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to clear the output on the screen when someone clicks the button again.

```
def eval_click():
    if entry_buysell.get().lower() == 'b':
        stoploss = (float(entry_price.get()) - float(entry_stop_loss.get()))
        take_profit = (float(entry_profit.get()) - float(entry_price.get()))
        ratio = take_profit/stoploss
        if ratio > 2.5:
            output = Label(reasons_window,text="TRADE, risk seems ok.")
            output.grid(row=1, column=2)
        else:
            output = Label(reasons_window,text="DON'T TRADE")
            output.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

I have tried to use `output.destroy()` which basically destroys the text as soon as it gets made.

I am not sure what the correct procedure is for this. The user might make changes to the input fields and the output switches but it gets overwritten on the last message.

Comment: Create the `output` label outside the function, then update its text using `output['text'] = '...'` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can first save the button click to a variable to check how many times a user has pressed the button in your case 2 times then check that variable in the function. Now you have two options

1. If you don't want to use that label again then just delete it with `l1.destroy()` and also add `l1.winfo_exists()` in the `if` condition to check if the widget exist or not.

   ```py
   if track_clicks > 0 and l1.winfo_exists():
       l1.destroy()
   ```
2. If you want to use the label later in the program then just unpack it with `pack_forget()` or `grid_forget()` / `place_forget()` for *grid* and *place* geometry managers respectively.

   ```py
   if track_clicks > 0:
       l1.pack_forget()
   ```
3. You can also do `l1.config(text='')` which remove the text of the label.

---

*Here is a sample:*

```py
import tkinter as tk

track_clicks = 0
def click():
    global track_clicks
    if track_clicks > 0 and l1.winfo_exists():
        l1.destroy() # destroys the label
    track_clicks += 1

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="DON'T TRADE")
l1.pack()
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Click :)', command=click)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
output.delete('1.0', END)
```

Assuming you are using Python3?

Comment: Getting this error: >AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'delete'. Yes I am using python3.6

Comment: `.delete` is an `Entry` method